# What control should I use when doing this in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Below is my snapshot. In this snapshot I have to make the boot control like images when I click image#1 then image#1 show on the upper side UIImageView I also define on the image... image#1 .. image#1000

so what controls should I use? I think I should use UIScrollView but I don't know what is the height and width I should take for that because UIScrollView has only game of height and width and also how to define click control on them.

[image: sample image]

I want some slider look like .. I slide the below images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will want to use a UIScrollView for this. The width and height will have to be calculated dynamically based off how many images you have and their dimensions.

To perform actions on touches, you will have to either encapsulate each image into a subclass view and handle the touches, or use gesture recognizers.

See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I would use UIButton for the bottom images and UIImageView for the top view.

Comment: i said those are dynamic images not the static... and i think its very bad practice to initiate 1000 buttons :)